# Upgrading Ubuntu Core 16

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-core

We have about 100 Ubuntu Core 16 devices deployed at the moment. The most attractive thing about Core to our team is that updates are automatic and transactional.

It's unclear to me if there is or will be a smooth way to move from Core 16 to 18. Given that the kernel and OS are snapped, I'm tempted to believe this process would be much more simple and reliable than a do-release-upgrade on a classic Ubuntu install.

If there's not a way to transition to 18, anyone knows what the EOL on 16 is?

Answer (score 0):

I luckily only run once device like this.
My advice would be to put them untder maintenance and make it canonical's problem.
I've used (at first, then I learned) and seen so many Ubuntu subprojects and they always dropped them...

Comment: Ironically it's all that maintenance money that funds pie in the sky projects.